# How to retrieve data only from 1 table (without its relational table) in CakePHP?

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have 3 tables (`projects`, `sentiments`, and `tweets`). All those tables have a relationship. What I need is to retrieve data only from table `projects`.

When I am retrieving the data with `$this->Project->find('all')`, the results gave me all the data from its relational table too.

When I try to use raw SQL query with `$this->Project->query('SELECT * FROM projects')`, it still gives me the same results.

How to retrieve data ONLY from `projects` table in CakePHP?

Comment: You should make it a habit to put `$recursive = -1` in your AppModel and only raise it when absolutely necessary :) Not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set recursiveness to -1.

```
$this->Project->find(
    'all',
    array( 'recursive' => -1 )
);
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Comment: Also checkout how to use the `Containable` behavior.